# Play framework - view template input text default value set to model's field string with space inside

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I need to display some text field of a model in my view. I passed the model "obj" to the view where there is a string column "somefield", and I have something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value=@obj.somefield>
```

However, if the string for obj.somefield contains white space, only the first word will be displayed. Is there anything I can do to display the whole string?

Comment: Try value="@obj.somefield"

Comment: @cYn that works! thx a lot cyn! can you reply as an answer so i can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
value="@obj.somefield"
```